# data is not passing on blur of a text field in remote in form validation

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am using jquery validate function and also using remote functionality to pass variables to another page foruniqueness checking. Please check the code given below.

Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#frmForm").validate({

rules: {
dep: "required",
type: "required",
stnd: "required",


clnum: {
required: true,
remote: {
url: "../admin/checkEmail.php?data=clausenum",
data: { stnd: $('#stnd').val()},
}
},
clause: "required"

},
messages: {
dep: "**",
type: "**",
stnd: "**",


clnum: {
required:"**",

remote: "already exists"
},
clause: "**"

}
});
});
</script>
```

Here the value stnd is blank. stnd is a dropdown field.

```
<select class="form-control valid" name="stnd" id="stnd" style="width:120px;" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="">select </option>
<option value="OHSAS 18001:2007">OHSAS 18001:2007</option>
<option value="ISO 14001:2015">ISO 14001:2015</option>
<option value="ISO 9001:2015">ISO 9001:2015</option>
<option value="IMS-ISO 14001, OHSAS 18001">IMS-ISO 14001, OHSAS 18001</option>
<option value="Safety Audit IS 14489">Safety Audit IS 14489</option>
<option value="Priority Inspection">Priority Inspection</option>
</select>
```

the value of stnd is not passing to the checkEmail.php

```
remote: {
url: "../admin/checkEmail.php?data=clausenum",
data: { stnd: $('#stnd').val()},
}
```

from the console we can see the value of stnd is blank.other values are passing correctly

```
http://test.com/admin/checkEmail.php?data=clausenum&clnum=10&stnd=
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: this mean that `$w['auditstandard'];` doesn't have values

Comment: stnd value is not passing it is balank. from the console http://test.com/admin/checkEmail.php?data=clausenum&clnum=10&stnd=

Comment: dropdown has values..but it is not passing to the checkEmail.php

Comment: try `$('#stnd option:selected').val()`

Comment: tried but no change. still stnd is blank.http://test.com/admin/checkEmail.php?data=clausenum&clnum=10&stnd=